# Loading a Lightbox variant when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, triggers, lightbox, onload

Currently a lightbox is triggered when a visitor clicks a certain link on my page. However, as an introduction to new users I'd also like to show the lightbox when a visitor loads a page.

I've been looking into click events, but I can't seem to get it to work. Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

The site is located on http://wandree.websites.xs4all.nl/test, and the lightbox is currently triggered when you press the image of the tv located in the sidebar.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the `head` section of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Call the lightbox function.
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how do I know which code actually triggers the lightbox? Is there a way to track this with firebug or other tools?

Comment: @Squrler: Inspect with firebug the image that triggers the lightbox. I think you can see it this way.

Comment: Ehm, I can't see how; I should probably inspect the a element thats the trigger, but then which Firebug panel or functionality should I use to find the code?

Comment: The inspect eement function. The one with the pointer. I can see your link has `rel="wp-video-lightbox"`. Start looking for the script that uses this attribute.

Comment: I found the script which is being loaded, its prettyPhoto. I was wondering if there was an easy way of finding out exactly which javascript command is executed when I click the link. I imagine that if I know that, I could use your suggested code. Right now, I just don't know where to look...

Comment: Check this page http://www.socreative.tv/blog/tag/prettyphoto/ .There is a javscript section about how to launch prettyPhoto.

Comment: Ok, so I'm going crazy: I've tried piecing together this code:

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a[rel^='wp-video-lightbox']").prettyPhoto({showTitle:false});
});

function prettyLaunch(linkurl, title) {
   document.getElementById("bldndktr_video").href = linkurl;
   document.getElementById("bldndktr_video").title = title;
   $("#bldndktr_video").trigger('click');
}
</script>

Tried placing it in the header and in the footer. Nothing works. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: The code must be in the `head` section. Check for the `name` and `id` of the elements. Do you have any error?